# Is SPCache a farm-wide cache?

Tags: caching

The [MSDN documentation on the `SPCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.objectcache.spcache.aspx) leaves very much to the imagination. But since it sounds interesting, **I'm wondering whether it is a farm-wide cache. Does anyone know?**

Currently I'm caching using the `System.Web.Cache`, but this makes flushing cache entries across the farm difficult, so a built-in farm-wide solution would be quite preferable.

Is the `SPCache` the same as the "object cache"?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447317/spcache-vs-httpruntime-cache. It would be interesting to know all the details.

Comment: @Kit Interesting, didn't see that. Curious that Michael thinks it is well documented. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, compared to the usual SharePoint documentation it's pretty well documented :)

I'm pretty sure it's not Farm Wide. Essentially it is a thread-safe Dictionary in memory of the server that uses it, and I have not seen anything that synchronizes it across the farm (I was planning to build my own object-cache for that purpose at some point).

Comment: Thanks. Guess I'll use shorter cache times instead of building something farm-wide.

Answer (score 14):

If you want a multi-server high performance cache consider using the AppFabric cache.

Comment: Agreed, Velocity also suppports claims based auth so it's quite easy to set up in a secure manner.